# Push the checked item at the top of the list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a checkbox with dynamic list item.I want to push the checked item at the top of the list in onload the list.

I have tried as in below snippet.I tried to change the color of the checked item.color get changed but not pushed the item to top of the list.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='geo[]']").each(function(){
if ($(this).is(":checked")){
     
      $(this).prop("checked",true);
    $(this).parent('li').css('background-color','#3875D7');
     $(this).parent('li').prepend($(this));
    
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
<li tabindex="0" class="even" ><input type="checkbox" value="US_East" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_East" ><label for="geo_US_East" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">US East</label></li>
<li tabindex="0" class="odd" ><input type="checkbox" value="US_West" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_West" ><label for="geo_US_West" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">US West</label></li>
<li tabindex="0" class="even checked" ><input type="checkbox" value="NSU" name="geo[]" id="geo_NSU" checked="checked"><label for="geo_NSU" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">NSU</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is the php tag relevant?

Comment: Did you want it to change dynamically as well (i.e. when a different checkbox is checked)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='geo[]']").each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).prop("checked",true);
        $(this).parent('li').css('background-color','#3875D7');
        $(this).parents('ul').prepend($(this).parent('li'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
<li tabindex="0" class="even" ><input type="checkbox" value="US_East" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_East" ><label for="geo_US_East" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">US East</label></li>
<li tabindex="0" class="odd" ><input type="checkbox" value="US_West" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_West" ><label for="geo_US_West" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">US West</label></li>
<li tabindex="0" class="even checked" ><input type="checkbox" value="NSU" name="geo[]" id="geo_NSU" checked="checked"><label for="geo_NSU" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">NSU</label></li>
</ul>
```

This is the only code that has changed:

```
$(this).parents('ul').prepend($(this).parent('li'))
```

The `parents()` selector gets all parents, not just the adjacent parent. Then prepend the parent of the current input item which is the whole `li`, that will be added at the beginning of the `ul` list

Answer (score 2):

You could reach the `ul` tag as the parent of your `li` first, then prepend the list item `li` to the `ul` list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='geo[]']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parent('li').css('background-color', '#3875D7');
      let item = $(this).parent('li');
      let list = $(item).parent('ul');
      $(list).prepend(item);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
  <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="US_East" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_East"><label for="geo_US_East" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">US East</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input type="checkbox" value="US_West" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_West"><label for="geo_US_West" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">US West</label></li>
  <li tabindex="0" class="even checked"><input type="checkbox" value="NSU" name="geo[]" id="geo_NSU" checked="checked"><label for="geo_NSU" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox">NSU</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I hope this helps you further, just implemented the list, not the color you want.

Edit: Add Color

```js
var list = $("ul");
var unorderedList= list.children();

list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
    var i = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var checked = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
    
    for (i = 0; i < unorderedList.length; i++) {
        if (unorderedList[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
            checked.appendChild(unorderedList[i]);
            unorderedList[i].style.backgroundColor ="red";
        } else {
            unchecked.appendChild(unorderedList[i]);
            unorderedList[i].style.backgroundColor ="white";
        }
    }
    list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checklist">
<li><label for="geo_US_East" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" value="US_East" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_East" >US East</label></li>
<li><label for="geo_US_West" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" value="US_West" name="geo[]" id="geo_US_West" >US West</label></li>
<li><label for="geo_NSU" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" value="NSU" name="geo[]" id="geo_NSU">NSU</label></li>
</ul>
```